# Git : Pushing to Remote Repository Works Fine. Now How To Deal With New Branch?

Tags: git

In last 2 months I'm using git just for backup my codes. so basically I'm dealing with my server (example.NET) and bitbucket.org as remote repository.

here's what I'm doing every day during development process :

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'some comments'
git push origin master
```

and today, I must deploy my codes in the real server (example.COM), so I decided to make a branch from master. named `public-beta`.

```
git fetch && git checkout public-beta
```

since this real server (example.COM) is user generated content (pics, videos, articles), I'm regularly also do commit and push to remote repository as I did in development server.

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'some comments'
git push origin public-beta
```

my question is...

if I make some new features on development server (example.NET) a.k.a `master branch` and it only change or create 3 files, for example : `test1.php`, `test2.php` and `test3.php`, how to merge this 3 files into `public-beta` branch without overwriting all user files?

please note that in `master branch`, user files are empty or maybe fewer than `public-beta`.

that's all I need to know. I really new in this git terminology, I really appreciate your help. thank you very much.

Comment: You can merge the changes from master to the new branch or cherry-pick the specific commits that you want to the new branch

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [git workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) that I would highly recommend. That way you can solve all your merges, pulls and pushes on a safe local branch before committing to a release branch (public-beta).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this where you just merge the two branches (it may look similar to this):

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

$ git merge public-beta
Updating 423b692..eac62ab
Fast-forward
 plan |    3 +
 3 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 plan
```

If there are different versions of the same files in both branches and you merge, you may run into a merge conflict. If that is the case, then you would need to work out which version(s) from what branch(s) you want.